# Invalid column name error in WHERE clause, column selected with CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause, calculated-columns

I have a (rather complicated) SQL statement where I select data from lots of different  tables, and to cope with a bad legacy data structure, I have a couple of custom columns that get their values based on values from other columns. I have currently solved this with `CASE` statements:

```
 SELECT
     ...,
     CASE channel
         WHEN 1 THEN channel_1
         WHEN 2 THEN channel_2
         ...
         ELSE 0
     END AS ChannelValue,
     CASE channelu
         WHEN 1 THEN channelu_1
         WHEN 2 THEN channelu_2
         ...
         ELSE '0'
     END AS ChannelWithUnit,
     ...
 FROM 
     ... 
 --rest of statement continues with multiple joins and where/and clauses...
```

I get all the results I expect when executing the query in MS SQL Server Management Studio, and the column names are listed as I have specified in my `AS` clauses. However, for some reason I'm not allowed to use the conditional values in a `WHERE` statement. If I add

```
AND ChannelValue > Limit * p.Percentage / 100
```

at the end of the query, I get an error on that line saying

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 152
>   Invalid column name 'ChannelValue'

Why is this not allowed? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only part of the SQL Statement where it is valid to use an alias declared in the `SELECT` list is the `ORDER BY` clause. For other parts of the query you just have to repeat the whole CASE expression and trust the optimiser to recognise it is the same.

If you are on SQL2005+ you can use a CTE to avoid this issue which sometimes helps with readability.

```
WITH YourQuery As
(

 SELECT
     Limit, 
     Percentage,
     CASE channel
         WHEN 1 THEN channel_1
         WHEN 2 THEN channel_2
         ...
         ELSE 0
     END AS ChannelValue,
     CASE channelu
         WHEN 1 THEN channelu_1
         WHEN 2 THEN channelu_2
         ...
         ELSE '0'
     END AS ChannelWithUnit,
     ...
 FROM 
)

select ...
FROM YourQuery WHERE
ChannelValue > Limit * Percentage / 100
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use `ChannelValue` column name in the where clause at the same `select` level.
You will have to put this whole `select` in a subquery.

```
select ....
from 
( 
your select query
) as innerSelect
where ChannelValue > Limit * p.Percentage / 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE - something like

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
     ..., 
     CASE channel 
         WHEN 1 THEN channel_1 
         WHEN 2 THEN channel_2 
         ... 
         ELSE 0 
     END AS ChannelValue, 
     CASE channelu 
         WHEN 1 THEN channelu_1 
         WHEN 2 THEN channelu_2 
         ... 
         ELSE '0' 
     END AS ChannelWithUnit, 
     ... 
 FROM  
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE ChannelValue > Limit * p.Percentage / 100
```

Answer (score -2):

```
-- SOMETHING FROM ADVENTURE WORKS THIS WORKS AS THE ABOVE POSTER
--- USING 'WITH CTE AS'
-- MY ANSWER TO A QUERY

WITH CTE AS
 (
 SELECT HE.Gender AS [GENDER], HE.HireDate AS [HIREDATE],      HE.BirthDate AS [BIRTHDATE],
CASE
WHEN DATEPART(YY,[BIRTHDATE]) BETWEEN 1962 AND 1970 AND [GENDER] = 'M' AND DATEPART(YY,[HIREDATE]) > 2001  THEN 'MALE'
WHEN DATEPART(YY,[BIRTHDATE]) BETWEEN 1972 AND 1975 AND [GENDER] = 'F' AND DATEPART(YY,[HIREDATE]) BETWEEN 2001 AND 2002 THEN 'FEMALE'
ELSE 'NOTREQUIRED'
END AS [RESULT]
FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] AS HE
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE [RESULT] <> 'NOTREQUIRED' -- GOT THIS TOO WORK NO FEMALES IN RESULT
ORDER BY [RESULT]
```