# SQL QUERY case with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql query where I have to get records count, I am getting counts correctly with the current query but I want to only get counts for records where 'Unchecked Count' is not zero.

```
   SELECT        
    dbo.Customer.AccountNo AS Cust_Acc_No, 
    dbo.Customer.Name AS [Customer Name], 
    dbo.Customer.Adrs1 AS Cust_Address_1,    
    dbo.Customer.Adrs2 AS Cust_Address_2, 
    dbo.Customer.City AS Cust_City, 
    dbo.Customer.Province, 
    dbo.Customer.PostalCode AS Cust_Postal_Code, 
    dbo.Customer.Email1 AS Email, 
    CAST(dbo.Customer.AccStatus AS int) AS [Account Status], 
    dbo.Customer.ID AS CID, 
    case when  COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) <  
         sum( CASE WHEN (dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy IS NULL OR
            (LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy)) = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    then  COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) else
         sum( CASE WHEN (dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy IS NULL OR
         (LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy)) = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    end as [Unchecked Count],
    case when  COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) <  
         sum( CASE WHEN (dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy IS not NULL OR
            (LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy))! = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    then  COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) else
         sum( CASE WHEN (dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy IS not NULL OR
            (LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy))! = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    end as [Checked_Count],
    COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) as Total

   FROM            
    dbo.Customer inner JOIN dbo.Manifest ON dbo.Customer.AccountNo = dbo.Manifest.FKAccountNo

   GROUP BY 
    dbo.Customer.AccountNo, 
    dbo.Customer.Name, 
    dbo.Customer.Adrs1, 
    dbo.Customer.City, 
    dbo.Customer.Province, 
    dbo.Customer.Adrs2, 
    dbo.Customer.Email1, 
    dbo.Customer.PostalCode, 
    dbo.Customer.AccStatus, 
    dbo.Customer.ID,Manifest.FKAccountNo
```

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Some non ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Thank you jarlh and a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: You have `[Checked_Count]` with underscore and `[Unchecked Count]` without it. Is it your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the result of the other query.
`SELECT * FROM ( <your query> ) AS T WHERE [Unchecked Count] > 0`

Answer (score 2):

Try `Having` clause after your `group by` clause

```
having [Unchecked Count] > 0
```

Full query

```
SELECT        dbo.Customer.AccountNo AS Cust_Acc_No, dbo.Customer.Name AS [Customer Name], dbo.Customer.Adrs1 AS Cust_Address_1, dbo.Customer.Adrs2 AS Cust_Address_2, dbo.Customer.City AS Cust_City, 
                     dbo.Customer.Province, dbo.Customer.PostalCode AS Cust_Postal_Code, dbo.Customer.Email1 AS Email, CAST(dbo.Customer.AccStatus AS int) AS [Account Status], dbo.Customer.ID AS CID, 
                    case when  COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) <  sum( CASE WHEN (dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy IS NULL OR
                     (LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy)) = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                     then  COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) else
                     sum( CASE WHEN (dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy IS NULL OR
                     (LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy)) = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                     end
                     as [Unchecked Count],
                      case when  COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) <  sum( CASE WHEN (dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy IS not NULL OR
                     (LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy))! = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                     then  COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) else
                     sum( CASE WHEN (dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy IS not NULL OR
                     (LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy))! = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                     end
                     as [Checked_Count],
                     COUNT(dbo.Manifest.ID) as Total

                     FROM            dbo.Customer inner JOIN
                     dbo.Manifest ON dbo.Customer.AccountNo = dbo.Manifest.FKAccountNo
                     GROUP BY dbo.Customer.AccountNo, dbo.Customer.Name, dbo.Customer.Adrs1, dbo.Customer.City, dbo.Customer.Province, dbo.Customer.Adrs2, dbo.Customer.Email1, dbo.Customer.PostalCode, dbo.Customer.AccStatus, 
                     dbo.Customer.ID,Manifest.FKAccountNo
    having [Unchecked Count] > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you AlexanderW and Shakti for your answers.I tried both of your suggestions but 'Unchecked Count' is  a alias, that is why I was getting 'invalid Column error'. But your answers helped me to solve the problem. Here is how it is working now, please let me know if you have better suggestion/s..

```
WITH OnlyUnchecked AS(<MyQuery>)
SELECT * 
FROM OnlyUnchecked 
WHERE [Unchecked Count]>0
```

Comment: I do not know much about sql server syntax. May be you can try UncheckedCount  (without space and bracket)

Comment: Above mentioned query in my reply is working.  I referred to this question for the error     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264950/invalid-column-name-error-in-where-clause-column-selected-with-case

Comment: i forgot to give the subquery an alias name. i changed my nswer above. It is good, that you have found the working variant. I would rather suggest to consider if you can (and need) to optimize the query. You do not need to calculate the `[Checked_Count]` field for the rows with `[Unchecked Count] < 0`. So you can calculate `[Unchecked Count]` in sub-query and the `[Checked_Count]` in the outer query. The sub-query should contains all original fields needed for the calculating `[Checked_Count]` such as `dbo.Manifest.ID` and `dbo.Manifest.CheckedBy`.